# Connecting to Multiple Instances of Skype via Java

Tags: java, skype, skype4java

I'm developing an application that will require integration with skype chat messaging.

I've figured out most of the problem with handling integration with Skype (via Skype4Java) but I've run into one snag.

I want to be able to use Skype4Java (or ANY Java Skype API) that will allow me to connect to MULTIPLE running instances of Skype.  Right now I have four instances of Skype running on my Windows server, but when I try to send a chat via `Skype.chat(String);` it will only randomly connect to ONE of the FOUR running instances of Skype.

Comment: If this is just for you to test if your system is working..... Just use another laptop or something running skype.... Cuz i don't think you can do what you want..

Comment: No, it's not for me to test... I already know how to launch multiple instances of Skype on the same machine and that's not the issue.  The issue is getting the API to connect to all the instances and be able to interact with (i.e. send chat messages) from all the running instances programmatically.